# C# Expression Tree's always wrapping with ()

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm trying to create an Expression tree that will determine if a line in a word document is deleted or not.

I'm looping through a collection of dependencies where I have a comparisonExpression:

```
comparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(attribute.AttributeValue), Expression.Constant(dependency.AttributeValue));
```

As I loop through I have a dependencyExpression (which is the overall expression) that gets appended too.

```
dependencyExpression = Expression.And(dependencyExpression, comparisonExpression);
```

Now if I have 3 dependencies the result will be:

```
((("29 5/8" (753mm)" == "29 5/8" (753mm)") And ("43" (1092mm)" == "43" (1092mm)")) Or ("Red" == "Black"))
```

when it really should be like:

```
(("29 5/8" (753mm)" == "29 5/8" (753mm)") And ("43" (1092mm)" == "43" (1092mm)") Or ("Red" == "Black"))
```

Every time I do any Expression.Whatever() it always adds the parenthesis on the outside. Is there a way to control this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean operators are binary meaning that they take two operands. The evaluating system needs some kind of precedence to determine how to evaluate the expression.

Note that

```
(F and T) or T = T
F and (T or T) = F
```

How should the evaluator know which version is the correct one if you only pass him

```
F and T or T
```

That is why you need to tell him with parentheses which expression to evaluate first.

Comment: Well the reason I don't need to know the order is being I'm letting the user decide the order in an admin application. In that administration side the specify the grouping operators

Comment: Is there no way of doing that?

Comment: Well then I don't quite understand your problem.

Comment: @Ryan you need to build your expressions in the order that will result in the correct grouping.  You will need to determine the order based on the users use of your admin interface.  Your interface will need to allow the user to build either of the two examples Damokles gave.